# What does <<= mean in an sbt configuration file?

Tags: scala, sbt

I've been searching the sbt docs, google and [symbol hound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=sbt+%3C%3C%3D) for a while and can't locate any information on this `<<=` operator that appears in some sbt configuration files I've inherited. What is it?

Any pointer to existing doc or an explanation here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<<=`, in SBT version <= 0.12.4 means you define the value on the left using other key's value(s), on the right. See the [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Getting-Started/More-About-Settings.html#computing-a-value-based-on-other-keys-values)

Comment: Thank you!! I was looking at docs for more recent versions which don't mention it anymore. Looks like we're running sbt 0.13.8, any idea how this is interpreted in versions > 0.12.4? Is this deprecated? I'm surprised docs for my version don't mention it even though it appears to be doing something...

Comment: It's been replaced : http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/More-About-Settings.html#computing-a-value-based-on-other-keys-values